# Wireless Driver not working

Tags: windows-10, wifi-driver

Please, after the upgrade to windows 10 from windows 7, I found out that my WiFi wasn't working anymore then I checked the WiFi driver and found out it wasn't working properly, I have no connection to the Internet without my WiFi, please I need a fix for this.
It's Acer Ferrari laptop with
Broadcom 4321AG 802.11a/b/g/draft-n Wi-Fi Adapter

Comment: Can you please add the make and model of your Wi-Fi adapter?

Comment: You need to provide more info. What computer? What wifi model? We can't just guess what hardware you have. Is the PC/Laptop/etc that you have is supported by Windows 10? Do you have USB to Ethernet (or USB WiFi) adapter you can use temporarily to download the drivers for it? (Windows 10 is surprisingly good at finding drivers for hardware)

Comment: What model of ``Acer Ferrari`` are you talking about (1000, 1100 or 1200)? If you're not sure about the model connect your machine to the internet via cable and run the [Acer autodetect tool](http://global-download.acer.com/SupportFiles/Files/SNID/APP/SerialNumberDetectionTool.exe)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are not running to the known issue with older VPN clients causign Wifi not working. It happened to me by having PulseSecure and I seen it with Cisco as well. [Here is a detailed description](http://www.redmondpie.com/fix-no-wi-fi-available-after-windows-10-upgrade-issue-heres-how/)

Comment: This answer could have better served as a comment.